# How do I go about solving this and finding the value of v(t)?

Tags: capacitor, circuit-analysis, resistors

[image]

I'm very sorry if the solution turns out to be very basic, but I'm a very recent student and my teacher is less than happy to help.

edit: sorry for not posting my attempted solutions first.
[image]

Here is my try, I'm mostly not confident in how to approach v(t) since it is in series with the first 1 ohm resistor, and whether or not I could just find the voltage across the (1 ohm + 1 H) to find v(t), since they're in parallel with each other.

Comment: Calculate the frequency of your source from 'cos (150*t)' then calculate Z from inductor and capcitator at this frequency and combine them together with the resistors. Include the steps what you've done so far to your question and I'm sure someone helps if you got stuck.

Comment: C'mon, ask your teacher, don't be shy.

Comment: There are numerous ways to solve this. You have to be specific. Show us your attempt, where did you get stuck?

Comment: Homework no attempt at solution.

Comment: Derive the differential equation, then solve. How far have you travelled down that path?

Comment: I have added my previous attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Have you not get any notes from your teacher? What type of circuit analysis are you using?

Assuming your using complex numbers, one easy way is to first convert your circuit to phasor or frequency domain by finding the reactance's of the inductor and capacitor (jXL & JXC). Then find the total circuit impedance to the voltage source by adding the real component of the resistors (be careful with resistances and reactance's in parallel).

Then use ohms law to find the total circuit current that flows. Once you know the current there are numerous different methods you could use and should be straight forward.

But with this forum you must upload some attempted solutions for people to see your level and offer help.

Comment: \$ -jX_c\$, to be precise.

Comment: I've added my previous attempted solution. I'm very confused on how to approach v(t) in the circuit. Do I need to use voltage divider?

Comment: @LongPham Sorry, yes -jXC

Comment: @AmaiShopai I suggest you google 'series and parallel RLC circuits' and do some research on AC circuit analysis (if you have to use complex numbers). But there are other ways.